# Can't Find Global .gitconfig FIle

Tags: git, config

I was trying to make some updates to my global .gitconfig file on my Windows 7 machine.  I have Git installed via the https://git-scm.com/ for Windows.  The file was located at `C:\Users\MyName\.gitconfig`, but when I ran some commands, the file wasn't updated.

I unistalled Git (and removed the user .gitconfig) and reinstalled Git. The install didn't create a `C:\Users\MyName\.gitconfig` file.  However, if I run`git config --global user.name "My Name"`and do a `git config --list`, I see `user.name=My Name` in the list of attributes.

I still don't have a .gitconfig file in my user directory nor is there one in `C:\Users\MyName\.config\git\` directory.

Is there a command to find out where the global config file is?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

type:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

then you will see the location of file `.gitconfig`. (The command works on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Try running the following command see which file is opened in the editor.

```
git config --global -e
```

Comment: This is correct answer that I want. Sometime, you the .gitconfig file is not exist so we must create a new file.